# DHCP Discover : why don't other hosts reply with ICMP 'port unreachable'

Tags: networking, dhcp, port, icmp

When a host sends a DHCP Discover (port 67, UDP), why don't all the hosts (except the DHCP server) reply with an ICMP 'port unreachable' message. This would cause a huge amount of useless data going through the network.

Comment: @user1686 Oh, right, I didn't remember that about UDP. Anyhoo I'm still thinking the OP might have not worded the question exactly as he wanted to - what'd be the point of causing such useless traffic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This would cause a huge amount of useless data going through the network.

Well, that's exactly why they don't reply.

This is stated as an explicit requirement in [RFC 1122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1122) ("Re­quire­ments for Internet Hosts -- Com­mu­ni­ca­tion Layers"), section [3.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1122#page-38), and the commentary specifically points out UDP broadcasts as the reason:

> An ICMP error message MUST NOT be sent as the result of receiving:
>
> - an ICMP error message, or
> - a datagram destined to an IP broadcast or IP multicast address, or
> - a datagram sent as a link-layer broadcast, or
> - a non-initial fragment, or
> - a datagram whose source address does not define a single host -- e.g., a zero address, a loopback address, a broadcast address, a multicast address, or a Class E address.
>
> DISCUSSION:
>
> These rules will prevent the "broadcast storms" that have
> resulted from hosts returning ICMP error messages in
> response to broadcast datagrams.  For example, a broadcast
> UDP segment to a non-existent port could trigger a flood
> of ICMP Destination Unreachable datagrams from all
> machines that do not have a client for that destination
> port.  On a large Ethernet, the resulting collisions can
> render the network useless for a second or more.

IPv4 DHCP "discover" packets match both the 2nd and 3rd conditions.